# How to find last 10 entity whose specific columns is different in Croud Repository?

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, repository, spring-repositories

I'm developing a backend application on Spring Boot 2 and Croud Repository.

I have a table called MoneyTransfer, and table has columns called customerId and firmId.

I need to get last 10 different firms that customer transferred money.

Currently, I get users all money transfers and filter them. However, this method doesn't make sense because I get all elements in the database to find last 10. It may cause performance problem.

```
fun getList(customerId: String) {
   var list = mutableListOf<MoneyTransfer>()
   moneyTransferRepository.findByCustomerId(customerId).forEach {
      if (list.find(elem -> it.firmId == elem.firmId) == null) {
        list.add(it)
      } 
      if (list.size == 10) {
          return@forEach
      }
   }
   return list
}
```

Do you have any efficient solutuion that let me get last 10 different firmId without getting all database row?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Data along with Spring Boot, you can create a SQL Query to retrieve only the records you want and use it with @Query annotations.

For example:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

     @Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
     User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);

}
```

Documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: Thanks. So how can I get last 10 different record whose customerId given? Which query return this result

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (i'm not sure - can not test right now)

```
public interface MoneyTransferRepository extends JpaRepository<MoneyTransfer, Long> {

     MoneyTransfer findFirst10ByCustomerIdDesc(String customerId);

}
```

And sort result reverse in getList method

Answer (score 0):

Create custom `@Query` with pagination, this will help you optimize the query without getting all database row

```
@Repository
public interface MoneyTransferRepository extends CrudRepository<MoneyTransfer, String> {

@Query("SELECT m.firmId FROM MoneyTransfer m WHERE m.customerId = :customerId ORDER BY m.id DESC")
List<String> findFirmIdsByCustomerId(@Param("customerId") String customerId, Pageable pageable);

}
```

But you still will have to check the result with deferent `firmId` and check the result size of deferent `firmIds`, if it's less than 10 then in your case you will again make a request to the database and change `page` in `PageRequest`

```
moneyTransferRepository.findFirmIdsByCustomerId(customerId, PageRequest.of(0, 10));
```

P.S. I also tried this with `DISTINCT` but it ignores all duplicated `firmId` with the same `customerId`

Comment: Thanks. But probably I couldn't explain the problem. I need to get 10 different firmId. To get this, maybe I need to check 15 row. Is there any way to get this.

Comment: I think you can try change method's return type List<String> to Set<String> and get PageRequest with size 15 then if list size >= 10 get subList or else get next page from PageRequest and concat with the previous result